# jQuery and Livequery Help for onchange()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new with JS and jQuery and I am trying to show the selected value from a Select filed in two different place, I did this by using Javascript function. Which was using #ID. But I need to use Class name instead of #ID. I found jQuery Live for easy solution. Please help me anybody.  Here is my jsFiddle link.

Here I use two Select Options one is to select and view Selected Comment, another is to select and display Quantity. The comment option is okay in JS using #ID. I tried to get same result in Quantity Option by jQuery Livequery and by taking help from CLASS.

Plaese Help and Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/7013/

I actually Need Help for this part:

#########################

```
function selectQty(){
    $(".qtyClass").change(function(){
        var quantity= $(this[this.selectedIndex]).val();
        $('.pakQuantity1').html(quantity);
        $('.pakQuantity2').html(quantity);
    });
}
```

##########################

```js
function getOption(){
    var obj = document.getElementById("commentList");
    document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text ;
    document.getElementById('display1').innerHTML = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value ;
} 
          
function selectQty(){
    $(".qtyClass").change(function(){
        var quantity= $(this[this.selectedIndex]).val();
        $('.pakQuantity1').html(quantity);
        $('.pakQuantity2').html(quantity);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="http://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery/raw/master/jquery.livequery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form  method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="form">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>Add a comment:  </label>
        <select id="commentList"  name="sale_comments" onchange="getOption()">
            <option selected="">Choose a Comment</option>
            <option value="1">Extra Spicy</option>
            <option value="2">Extra Sugar</option>
            <option value="3">Alabama</option>
        </select>    
    </div>
                                                                            
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>Add Quantity:  </label>
        <select id="qtyDropdown" class="qtyClass" name="quantity" onchange="selectQty()">
            <option selected="" >Quantity</option>
            <option value="1" style="line-height:30px;">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>    
    </div>
</form>    

<div style=" padding:10px; border-radius:5px; border: 1px solid #666; " >
<!------ This lines are to Show data in Modal Box before Submit---->
    <h4><span ><strong>Package: </strong></span><span style="" class="name">Samsang 4GS </span></h4>  
    <h4><span ><strong>Price: </strong></span><span class="price"  style="" >1000</span>  
    <h4><span ><strong>VAT: </strong></span><span class="tax"  style="" >15%</span> </h4>
    <h4><span ><strong>Quantity: </strong></span>  <span class="pakQuantity1" id="displayQty2"  style="" >1</span></h4>
    <h4><span ><strong>Comment: </strong></span><span class="comment" name="comment" id="display2"  style="" >No Comments</span> </h4> 
</div>
    
<div>
    <span style="display:none;" class="name">Samsang 4GS </span>
    <br /> Name:<span class="price"  style="display:;" >1000</span> 
    <br /> vat:<span class="tax"  style="display:;" >15</span>
    <br /> Quantity:<span class="pakQuantity2" id="displayQty1"  style="display:;" >1</span>
    <br /> Commment No:<span class="comment " name="display1" id="display1"  style="display:;" ></span>   
</div>
```

Comment: Yours is ok, just no need to use live jquery , instead take a jquery from any CDN, here is the working demo http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/kb3gN/7014/

Comment: Thanks a lot @CodingAnt, I did this.

I tried with JoriO's suggestion and got the result and I did not tried with your suggestion. I will try.
Thanks again for help.

Answer (score 0):

**Here I used -->>**   http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

```js
   function getOption(){
var obj = document.getElementById("commentList");
document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text ;
document.getElementById('display1').innerHTML = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value ;
  } 
          
function selectQty(){
  $(".qtyClass").change(function(){
 var quantity= $(this[this.selectedIndex]).val();
    $('.pakQuantity1').html(quantity);
    $('.pakQuantity2').html(quantity);
    
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<form  method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="form">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<label>Add a comment:  </label>
<select id="commentList"  name="sale_comments" onchange="getOption()">
<option selected="">Choose a Comment</option>
<option value="1">Extra Spicy</option>
<option value="2">Extra Sugar</option>
<option value="3">Alabama</option>
</select> 
</div>
                   
<div class="col-sm-6">
<label>Add Quantity:  </label>
<select id="qtyDropdown" class="qtyClass" name="quantity" onchange="selectQty()">
<option selected="" >Quantity</option>
<option value="1" style="line-height:30px;">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select> 
</div>
</form> 

<div style=" padding:10px; border-radius:5px; border: 1px solid #666; " >
<!------ This lines are to Show data in Modal Box before Submit---->
<h4><span ><strong>Package: </strong></span><span style="" class="name">Samsang 4GS </span></h4>  
<h4><span ><strong>Price: </strong></span><span class="price"  style="" >1000</span>  
<h4><span ><strong>VAT: </strong></span><span class="tax"  style="" >15%</span> </h4>
<h4><span ><strong>Quantity: </strong></span>  <span class="pakQuantity1" id="displayQty2"  style="" >1</span></h4>
<h4><span ><strong>Comment: </strong></span><span class="comment" name="comment" id="display2"  style="" >No Comments</span> </h4> 
</div>
    
    
<div>
<span style="display:none;" class="name">Samsang 4GS </span>
<br /> Name:<span class="price"  style="display:;" >1000</span> 
<br /> vat:<span class="tax"  style="display:;" >15</span>
<br /> Quantity:<span class="pakQuantity2" id="displayQty1"  style="display:;" >1</span>
<br /> Commment No:<span class="comment " name="display1" id="display1"  style="display:;" ></span>   
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent and it saves a lot of time for me. Though already I spent a lot. Many Many Thanks JoriO.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CodingAnt, I did this. I tried with JoriO's suggestion and got the result. I did not tried with your suggestion yet. I will try. Thanks again for help.